# NPM install delete node modules NPM install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am adding a node module to a project of mine and I am not able to build the project till I do an npm install delete the node modules folder and do an npm install again. Just deleting the node modules and doing an npm install does not fix it.

Comment: Please add more information. Node, NPM versions, error output. Also did you tried cleaning cache and reinstalling node?

Comment: Please show the errors & output